# Selenium with NodeJS - the driver object loses context when returning from TinyMCE iframe

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

First, I login on a separate page to have access to the page with the form.

**After logging in correctly and after switching to the page with the form**, I have access to all its elements and I can freely edit them. **One of the form element is the TinyMCE iframe**.

**After entering the iframe and modifying it, I don't know how to return to the native form and click on submit...**

Here is my code (*my.js*):

```
const loginUrl = 'https://www.example.com/login';
const formUrl = 'https://www.example.com/form';
const {Builder, By, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const driver_ch = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
driver_ch.manage().window().maximize();
driver_ch.get(loginUrl);

const loginLink = driver_ch.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('#login-box')), 20000);

loginLink.click().then(function() {

  driver_ch.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('#login'))).sendKeys('user_name');
  driver_ch.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('#password'))).sendKeys('secret_password');
  driver_ch.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('#submit-login'))).click();

}).then(function() {

  driver_ch.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('.form-action'))).then(function() {

    driver_ch.get(formUrl);

    driver_ch.switchTo().frame(driver_ch.findElement(By.id("edit-body-und-0-value_ifr")));
    driver_ch.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('tinymce'))).sendKeys('Glory! Glory! Hallelujah!');
```

Until now everything work, but this not:

```
driver_ch.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

and this also not:

```
driver_ch.switchTo().parentFrame();
```

so this could not be done...

```
    driver_ch.findElement(By.css('#edit-submit')).click();
  });
});
```

Error messege after runing *my.js* script:

```
node my.js 
(node:3955) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/user1/test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:585:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/user1/test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:554:13)
    at Executor.execute (/home/user1/test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:489:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:3955) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3955) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Changing the driver from *Chrome* to *FireFox* did not solve the problem.

#### Edited:

Thank you *@DebanjanB* for your suggestions in your answer.

I have updated the Chrome browser and Chrome driver as you suggested, but unfortunately it still doesn't work...

I get this error message now:

```
node my.js 
(node:24587) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.70)
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/home/user1/test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/user1/test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:563:13)
    at Executor.execute (/home/user1/test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:489:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:24587) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promis
e which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:24587) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zer
o exit code.
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
node my.js 
(node:3955) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/user1/test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:585:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/user1/test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:554:13)
    at Executor.execute (/home/user1/test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:489:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:3955) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3955) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to interact with the desired element i.e. the *defaultContent* / *parentFrame*.

I don't see any major issue in your code trials. However your main issue seems to be **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.41*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

- You are using *chrome= chrome=74.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v74.0.3729.6*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v74**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.41* and the *Chrome Browser v74.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to current [ChromeDriver v78.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 78.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v78.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Thank you @DebanjanB for your suggestions in your answer!!!

Unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem.

Would you see the edit of the question and maybe can suggest something more?